# Installing GCC (gfortran) on Heroku-16 stack

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am developing a python app on Heroku server (Heroku-16 stack) using Django framework. I would like to use gfortran on the server. However, this stack version of Heroku does not include a C compiler as stated in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages

Can I install a buildpack to overcome this problem or do I have to downgrade to cedar-14 version which includes GCC?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, I have contacted the Heroku Support team and they have replied with three ways of tackling such problems.

1) Use the apt buildpack to install gfortran such as [this](https://github.com/ivahero/heroku-buildpack-apt). However, this buildpack is not officially supported so its usefulness may vary depending on the application.

2) Secondly, use [build manifest file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-yml-build-manifest) which also allows to install additional Ubuntu packages.

3) Lastly, build the app as a docker image which would allow to pull in the desired packages and then run the image using the Heroku [Container Runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)